# Python3 parsing array from a json file

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a json file like this with multiple variables

```
{
  "resource_folder_name": "my resources",
  "itunes_id":"some_item",
  "default_language":["en", "es", "in"],
  "default_country":["mt", "in", "uk", "usa"]
}
```

How can I iterate over it to create a dictionary structure similar to

```
{
  ["resource_folder_name"]= "my resources",
  ["itunes_id"]="some_item",
  ["default_language"]=["en", "es", "in"],
  ["default_country"]["mt", "in", "uk", "usa"]
}
```

Then I want to pass this dictionary to create a plist where I need to iterate through the list to add items.

What I have tried is

```
def return_params():
    filename = 'params.json'
    with open(filename) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

    local_vars = {}

    for var in data:
        print('Var = '+var + ' & Data = '+data[var])

        if('' not in data[var]):
            local_vars[var] = data[var]
        else:
            local_vars[var] = data[var]

    return local_vars
```

but this is capable of reading only

> key = string value

kind of data and not the list or dictionaries instead.

Comment: `data` is already your solution, why are you then adding more logic after `json.load()`?  It's already done!

Comment: You cannot use **list** as a key, it is unhashable. Better is to prefer **tuple** in place of that.